# Can an EASA Part 66 AME License be accepted by the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, easa

I am holder of an EASA Part 66 AME License (Category L3H / hot air balloon). Can it be accepted by the FAA so that I would be allowed to do maintenance and annual inspection of American-registered aircraft?

I did not find any form/application on the FAA website to get it approved/accredited.